# Dataframe doesn't show all columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am working in Python with the compas-scores dataset of 47 columns and 11757 rows (https://github.com/propublica/compas-analysis).

I've noticed that when I am calling the dataset, it doesn't shows me all the columns. Instead I have a column in the middle with three dots [...] (see the example in the screenshot). The import statement of pandas was: `import pandas as pd`

Is there a way to show all the 47 columns?

[compas-score screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gKjwb.png)

I would apreciate your help.

**SOLUTION:**

I had to maximize all the columns adding one piece of code. This solution has worked for me:

`pd.options.display.max_columns = None`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assuming your import statement is `import pandas as pd`

I'd suggest trying one of the below:

```
pd.options.display.max_columns = None
```

or

```
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
```

same can be used for `max_rows`:

```
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
pd.options.display.max_rows = None
```